# how to track down "this page contains both secure and nonsecure items"

Tags: internet-explorer, https

As far as I can tell, there are no unsecure items --- when I browse to the site with IE7 or FireFox 3 I don't get any such warning, but if I hit the site with IE6 I get the security informaiton dialog box "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items Do you want to display te nonsecure items?"

How can I track down the cause of that message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out it has nothing to do with nonsecure traffic per se, but with a hack that one of the HTML boys did --- they have an empty iframe (without a source) that they place on the page, so they can then do some placed content on top of that --- gut the iframe out of the code and the warning dialog box went away.  IE7/8 and FF doesn't do it.

AFter adding a blank.gif we're able to https to that gif (what a pain) and now it's all good.

Comment: An <iframe> with src="about:blank" triggers this message in IE6 but it's OK in IE7 and FF...

Answer (score 5):

Use Fiddler, after **clearing your cache**.  It'll show **everything** that your web browser fetches from the remote site.  Look for anything that's not https.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a link that starts with `http://` instead of `https://` it'll flag those warnings.

The good news is that at least some commercial websites (like Adobe, for Flash) provide `https://` versions of their site that redirect to `http://` so that you can get around those warnings.

Since you mentioned IE6; I'd also check your security level setting in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the page. Select "Show
  source code" (Or similar. I don't
  have an English IE).
- Search for
  "http://" and replace it with
  https:// in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-site images often caused this problem for me in the past.

If you are using Firefox, you can use the  [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) Add-on to do what Eric TenEyck suggested you do with Fiddler.

Plus make sure in your IE7 Security Settings you have Display mixed content set to "Prompt".